# Desactivar EOF después de leer EOF del flujo BufferedReader

Tags: java

tengo esto

```java
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(isr);

try
{
    String s1 = in.readLine();
    String s2 = in.readLine();
    System.out.println(s2);
} 
catch (IOException e) 
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

El resultado es null y no me deja volver a teclear un valor para s2, después de introducir eof en la primera llamada a readLine. Cómo puedo desactivar el EOF para poder volver a hacer llamadas después de un EOF?

Gracias. Un saludo

Answer (score 0):

eso me paso algunas veces, la forma mas fácil y rápida que encontré fue controlar la excepción con otro catch. Te dejo tu código con esta parte incluida con varias opciones.

```
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(isr);

try
{
    String s1 = in.readLine();
    String s2 = in.readLine();
    System.out.println(s2);
} 
catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} 
catch (EOFException f) { // Si mal no recuerdo es así que se escribe.
    // aqui podrias poner lo que quieras, te dejo varios ejemplo.
  System.out.print("Hasta Luego"); // si quieres dar una despedida
  System.out.print(""); // También un salto de linea.
  System.exit(0); //o simplemente que se termine la ejecución del programa.
}
```

Espero que te pueda ayudar, Saludos.